# String in python list is written with curly braces

Tags: python, string, format

I read list with 2 columns firstname and surname from csv file

```
    csv_reader_object = csv.reader(path, delimiter=';')
         for row in csv_reader_object:
```

I want to put the name into a contructor but alway get **{'Garfield'}** instead of **Garfield** as string

This one is fine:

```
print(f'Name: {", ".join(row)}')
```

These are not:

```
print(str({row[1]}))
print({row[1]})
```

How to get simple formatted string out of that list?

Comment: can you share a sample of the json? It sounds like the json does not contain raw string. It rather contains a string within an object.

Comment: `print(f"{row[0]} {row[1]}")` ?

Comment: Why do you put your 1 element of your list into a SET and then use the sets string-veriosn to print?!?  `print(str(row[1]))` or `print( row[1] )` which internally will call the `row[1].__str__()` are just fine

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Hello @r2ls, I believe you have to provide more information about your code and about what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extracting `row[1]` and then put it into [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (thus `{` and `}` you see) simply do not that, i.e. replace

```
print(str({row[1]}))
print({row[1]})
```

using

```
print(str(row[1]))
print(row[1])
```

Comment: That did it, seems to be copy&paste error. Lists and sets still a bit confusing for python newbie. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you place curly brackets around a string you are actually making a set of single element and when set is printed it is printed with those curly brackets as in

```py
>>> str({"hello"})
"{'hello'}"
>>>
```

you can fix this by removing those curly brackets as in

```py
print(str(row[1]))
print(row[1])
```